# Kendo ui scheduler group by date then by resource

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm creating a scheduler by using Kendo UI Scheduler, with horizontal grouping like [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/scheduler/resources-grouping-horizontal.html).
My problem is that I don't want one calendar for each resource like the mentioned example does. I only want one calendar displayed, but each day will provide one colomn for each resource. I've found an example that does exactly what I want [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/resourcegrouping/defaultcs.aspx) (check both "group by speaker" and "group by date" and then select week view), but this example is for Telerik (Kendo is the javascript version of telerik). I've tried to translate this example into working for Kendo UI by using the below code, but none of the options work.

*Basic kendo code*

```
$('#scheduler').kendoScheduler({
            date: new Date(),
            views: [
                { type: "day" },
                { type: "week", selected: true }
            ],
            group: {
                resources: ["Owner"]
            },
            resources: [
                {
                    field: "ownerId",
                    name: "Owner",
                    title: "Owner",
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                        { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                        { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
```

*How I've tried to group by date and then by resource*

```
resources: ["date", "Owner"]
resources: ["Date", "Owner"]
resources: [Date, "Owner"]
```

I have not provided another resource called "date"/"Date". In the Telerik example above you did not need to do that. The scheduler understod that you wanted to group by date.

Comment: I have same issue with Kendo Scheduler now, do you have any solution? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, my sultion to this problem was to rewrite the part in the kendo library which draws resources. Not a good solution, but my only option.

Comment: This is how I solved the problem by the way: http://karolinescoding.azurewebsites.net/?p=361

Comment: @KarolineBrynildsen any updated link with a working example? Unfortunately the link you provided us is broken..

Comment: @andrea here it is https://karolinescoding1.wordpress.com/2016/01/26/kendo-ui-scheduler-group-by-date-then-by-resource/ 

but remember that I did this a few years ago, so my solution may not be valid anymore